# Isosurface with cracks between LODs

Tags: computational-geometry, volumetric

I have an octree containing different LODs of an [isosurface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosurface) that was extracted using [Marching Cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes).

Neighbouring chunks show surfaces that do not line up if they have different LOD. See image below.

I find that stitching them up is a hairy and complicated affair, so I am looking at alternatives to Marching Cubes, but I am not sure if this will solve my problem?

[Dual Contouring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosurface#Dual_Contouring) would be a candidate. Its main advantage seems to be sharp-edges, but it is unclear to me if different LODs of a Dual Contour surface would line up.

Another is [Cubic Marching Squares](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecyy/publications/papers/Ho2005CMS.pdf). But again it is unclear if LODs match up in here.

To be clear: I do not use LOD to adaptively refine, based on geometry. I use LOD to have far away (from camera/vehicle) chunks in low resolution.

So my question: Does moving from MC to either DC or CMS solve the issue of LOD cracks in the surface?

[image: iso-surface showing cracks]